# Splitting an string into a string array.?

Tags: c#

I am facing a problem while executing a sql query in C#.The sql query throws an error when the string contains more than 1000 enteries in the IN CLAUSE .The string has more than 1000 substrings each seperated by ','.

I want to split the string into string array each containing 999 strings seperated by ','.

or

How can i find the nth occurence of ',' in a string.

Comment: what is your target DB? 1000 is not a lot for In clause if working with Sql Server (unless you have huge strings). Of course they might be better ways to send this data to your stored proc(?). Please share more details

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
string foo = "a,b,c";

string [] foos = foo.Split(new char [] {','});

foreach(var item in foos)
{
   Console.WriteLine(item);
}
```

Comment: I don't see how this finds the *nth occurence of `,` in a string.*

Comment: This doesn't fulfill the question's requrement at all.

Answer (score 0):

Pull the string from SQL server into a DataSet using a utilities code like

```
string strResult = String.Empty;
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
{
    cmd.Connection = conn;
    cmd.CommandText = strSQL;
    strResult = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
}
```

Get the returned string from SQL Server

Split the string on the ','

```
string[] strResultArr = strResult.Split(',');
```

then to get the nth string that is seperated by ',' (I think this is what you mean by "How can i find the nth occurence of ',' in a string." use

```
int n = someInt;
string nthEntry = strResultArr[someInt - 1];
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a regular expression and the `Index` property of the `Match` class:

```
// Long string of 2000 elements, seperated by ','
var s = String.Join(",", Enumerable.Range(0,2000).Select (e => e.ToString()));

// find all ',' and use '.Index' property to find the position in the string
// to find the first occurence, n has to be 0, etc. etc.
var nth_position = Regex.Matches(s, ",")[n].Index;
```

To create an array of strings of your requiered size, you could split your string and use LINQ's `GroupBy` to partition the result, and then joining the resulting groups together:

```
var result = s.Split(',').Select((x, i) => new {Group = i/1000, Value = x})
                         .GroupBy(item => item.Group, g => g.Value)
                         .Select(g => String.Join(",", g));
```

`result` now contains two strings, each with 1000 comma seperated elements.

Answer (score 0):

How's this:

```
    int groupSize = 1000;

    string[] parts = s.Split(',');
    int numGroups = parts.Length / groupSize + (parts.Length % groupSize != 0 ? 1 : 0);

    List<string[]> Groups = new List<string[]>();
    for (int i = 0; i < numGroups; i++)
    {
        Groups.Add(parts.Skip(i * groupSize).Take(groupSize).ToArray());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```
string line = "1,2,3,4";
var splitted = line.Split(new[] {','}).Select((x, i) => new {
                                                                Element = x,
                                                                Index = i
                                                            })
                                      .GroupBy(x => x.Index / 1000)
                                      .Select(x => x.Select(y => y.Element).ToList())
                                      .ToList();
```

After this you should just `String.Join` each `IList<string>`.

Answer (score -1):

```
//initial string of 10000 entries divided by commas
string s = string.Join(", ", Enumerable.Range(0, 10000));
//an array of entries, from the original string
var ss = s.Split(',');
//auxiliary index
int index = 0;

//divide into groups by 1000 entries
var words = ss.GroupBy(w =>
    {
        try
        {
            return index / 1000;
        }
        finally
        {
            ++index;
        }
    })//join groups into "words"
    .Select(g => string.Join(",", g));

//print each word
foreach (var word in words)
    Console.WriteLine(word);
```

---

Or you may find the indeces in the string and split it into substrings afterwards:

```
string s = string.Join(", ", Enumerable.Range(0, 100));
int index = 0;

var indeces =
Enumerable.Range(0, s.Length - 1).Where(i =>
    {
        if (s[i] == ',')
        {
            if (index < 9)
                ++index;
            else
            {
                index = 0;
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }).ToList();

Console.WriteLine(s.Substring(0, indeces[0]));
for (int i = 0; i < indeces.Count - 1; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(s.Substring(indeces[i], indeces[i + 1] - indeces[i]));
}
```

However, I would think over, if it was possible to work with the entries before they are combined into one string. And probably think, if it was possible to prevent the necessity to make a query which needs that great list to pass into the `IN` statement.